# How to specify JVM for Groovy

Tags: groovy, jvm

What JVM uses Groovy be default and how to specify another version?

Output from my server:

`$ groovy --version
Groovy Version: 2.4.5 JVM: 1.7.0_95 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)`

Comment: Have you got JAVA_HOME set? If so, try `unset JAVA_HOME`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've probably got `JAVA_HOME` pointing to the Java 7 jdk

If you unset it with

```
unset JAVA_HOME
```

Groovy should use the default JVM, the same as Java

Answer (score 2):

According to [this documentation page](http://www.groovy-lang.org/install.html#_install_binary), you can set the Java version of the Groovy installation by setting the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to the installed JDK:

> Set your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to point to your JDK. On OS X this is `/Library/Java/Home`, on other unixes its often `/usr/java` etc. If you’ve already installed tools like Ant or Maven you’ve probably already done this step.